# How to create alias tags using acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

If I type either aws or amazon, I get the following tags and StackOverflow somehow links the following tags but in reality there is only a single tag amazon-s3 with aws-s3 like a soft link.

```
amazon-s3
aws-s3
```

How do I achieve something similar with acts-as-taggable-on
Refer: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well, and opened an issue about it on the gem - https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/851#issuecomment-320332246